# Ogg audio in safari

Tags: flash, html, audio, mediaelement.js, ogg

How can I play .ogg audio files in safari without converting it to mp3? I use [mediaelements.js](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/) library to flash fallback and it works fine in chrome and firefox and plays both mp3 and ogg files, but in safari it plays only mp3. Looks like flash fallback of this library can't play audio/ogg.

Comment: Can confirm that OS X 10.8.2, Safari 6.0.2 with the Xiph Component plugin installed does not play any ogg-files (neither video nor audio).
http://www.xiph.org/quicktime/download.html

Answer (score 7):

Codec support in modern desktop browsers

```
Browser                      Ogg Vorbis     MP3     WAV

Firefox 3.6+                    ✓                   ✓

Safari 5+                                   ✓       ✓

Chrome 6                        ✓           ✓   

Opera 10.5+                     ✓                   ✓

Internet Explorer 9+                        ✓       ✓
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it. Question is can I play ogg in safari through flash plug in? If yes, what library better to use?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't play ogg in safari through flash.