# HTML5 audio player not working with jQuery on Safari or IE

Tags: jquery, html, safari

I am triggering HTML5 audio player with jQuery when clicked on an object. Everything works fine in chrome or firefox but it is not working in safari 8 or in IE 10. It is also not working in IOS 8.

```
<audio class="player-audio" src="http://spellout.org/resources/audio/int-icao/alfa.ogg"></audio>

<a class="play-audio" data-audio="alfa"><h6>Play Audio</h6></a>
```

---

```
$('.play-audio').click(function(){
    var audioPlayer = $('.player-audio');
    audioPlayer.trigger('play');
});
```

Can anyone explain me what is wrong with my method?

Here is the fiddle:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuhkr3wx/3/)

Comment: `ogg` is not supported in Safari and IE. Use `.mp3` http://stackoverflow.com/a/10583899/3639582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ogg` format is not supported in IE and Safari(unless you install a plugin). **[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)**

Desktop

```
Chrome        Firefox (Gecko)   Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari

(Yes)          3.5 (1.9.1)        Not supported     10.50   3.1 (must be installed separately, e.g. XiphQT)
```

Mobile

```
Safari Mobile

Not supported
```

Try changing the URL to `.mp3`. Works for me on IE.